How to define optional properties in Data Transfer Objects?
Below is my Data Transfer Object using Spatie\LaravelData\Data using Laravel Framework 9.52.16. In this definition $user_id is defined as optional property but yet when it is missing it throws an error.
<?php
namespace App\Http\DataTransferObjects\Listing;
use Spatie\LaravelData\Data;
use Spatie\LaravelData\Optional;

class ListingDTO extends Data
{
    public function __construct(public string $type, public string|Optional $user_id)
    {

    }
}


Exception
    "message": "App\\Http\\DataTransferObjects\\Listing\\ListingDTO::__construct(): Argument #2 ($user_id) not passed",
    "exception": "ArgumentCountError",
    ....

How can I define optional properties?

I'm not super-familiar with Laravel, but are you manually invoking the constructor, or is the framework. If it is you, I think you need to pass Optional::create() in order to make PHP happy.

I'm not sure where you got the string|Optional syntax from, but technically, you still need two arguments. I'd use string? $user_id = null in the declaration.

@UlrichEckhardt https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-data/v4/as-a-data-transfer-object/optional-properties it is in official documentation

Interesting. In any case, just arguing from the pure PHP side, your ctor takes two arguments. In the code where you try to create an instance, it does not provide a second parameter, which is why PHP at that point signals an error.

public string|Optional $user_id = new Optional() ? Also, what version of LaravelData you're using?

How are you creating the instance? Official docs use the equivalent of ListingDTO::from([ 'type' => 'type' ])

@OMiShah Laravel Framework 9.52.16
